# How can I programmatically run all my unit tests within my app and email failed tests list

Tags: java, maven-3, junit-runner

I have a requirement I must email  list of all my failed tests within my maven spring batch application to my PO in daily manner. Unfortunately I do not have access to any deployment tools like Teamcity so that I could set-up such warning emails. I must do it in my codes. And I am trying to avoid

- leave any trails of any of my test assertion failed exceptions in my logs
- have any repeated test piece of my test codes

  and finally email my noted failed test list and otherwise abandon email if all my tests have been passed.
  Can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do this, but it seems like it'd be a lot of work. Obviously you can't do this, but if the PO (Product owner?) wants this, they're out of luck unless I get resources for a Jenkins/Teamcity/etc. build tool. I'm not sure the PO has any business in the code anyway. (All opinion)

Comment: Most likely it's possible. You didn't specify what testing framework are you using, but JUnit/TestNG should have listeners and other helpers to achieve your goal.